# Modifying PHP date output

Tags: php, date, mktime

I'm generating the current day and the next upcoming six with this:

```
 <?php
     for($i=0; $i<=6; $i++){
         echo strtoupper(date("j",mktime(0, 0, 0, 0,date("d")+$i,0))."\n");
         echo "|";
     }  
 ?>
```

Which produces this (on February 8 when I'm writing this):

```
8 |9 |10 |11 |12 |13 |14 |
```

How do I do the following:

- Get rid of the space after each numeral
- Get rid of the trailing pipe

The output I'd like would be:

```
8|9|10|11|12|13|14
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This task is ideal for a `do..while` loop:

```
$i = 0;
do {
    echo strtoupper(date("j",mktime(0, 0, 0, 0,date("d")+$i,0)));
} while ($i++ < 6 && print "|");
```

The space is present because you had `\n` in your output. Any whitespace will be made into a space by your browser.

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun with `DateTime` classes (PHP 5.3+)

```
<?php
$start = new DateTime();
$interval = new DateInterval('P1D');
$period = new DatePeriod($start,$interval,6);

$days = array();
foreach($period as $date) {
  $days[] = $date->format('d');
}

$daysString = implode('|',$days);

echo $daysString;
```

Yeah... `DatePeriod` needs to implement some kind of interator to be useful...

Comment: +1 for prettiness. I would have used the DateTime classes, but, as you say, they are incompatible with loops other than `foreach`. If they implemented `Iterator`, it would be much better. You could make this shorter with `foreach (new DatePeriod(new DateTime, new DateInterval('P1D'), 6) as $date)`, though I guess that would reduce readability...

Answer (score 0):

You could use a variable and append to it for the text, and output the string after your for loop.

```
$output = '';
for($i=0; $i<=6; $i++){
    $output .= (date("j",mktime(0, 0, 0, 0,date("d")+$i,0))).'|';
}
$output = rtrim($output, '|');
echo $output;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for($i=0; $i<=6; $i++){
$dates[] = date('j', strtotime('+ '.($i+1).' days');
}
echo implode('|', $dates);
```